# Stop prePersist LifeCycleEvent being recursive in Doctrine2 Entiy

Tags: php, symfony, recursion, doctrine-orm, entity

I am using a the `prePersist` LifeCycleEvent to update an Entity, updating this Entity creates a loop as the object is re-saved over and over again to the database.

```
public function doSomething(LifecycleEventArgs $event)
{
     // Stuff here
     $em = $event->getEntityManager();
     $em->persist($entity);
     $em->flush();
}
```

How can I have the Entity update itself, without causing his recursive loop?

Comment: Is your `$entity` a new object? If it isn't, it will already be managed by doctrine and there is no reason to persist it into object manager again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the prePersist event is triggered before the entity is actually scheduled for insertion in the unit of work, you can just change the entity state here without having to manually call persist/flush.

Simply do your stuff in your callback and don't bother about the entity manager.

Comment: What if I am using preUpdate instead - is the same still true?

Comment: Mmh, I'm not quite sure about this one. I would say yes, but you might have to change already changed value through `$event->setNewValue('name', 'foo');` (But if you haven't changed the entity's name, then you can just do `$this->name = 'foo';`).